# GTA IV will not start

Tags: pc, steam, grand-theft-auto-iv

Last Year, I bought Grand Theft Auto IV on Steam (PC). After I installed it I played it for less that an hour, then I had to go out. The next day the game would not launch. The Launcher would appear, but when I press the 'Play' button, the loading cursor would appear for about 5 seconds, then disappear. No boxes would come up, and no related processes would be running. I have reinstalled the game several times since then but the same thing has happened ever since. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 9):

### Run as Administrator

First, completely exit Steam, and right-click on the shortcut which you use to launch Steam and select "Run as Administrator."  This step may be enough to fix the problem.  If not, continue below:

### Additional Installers

You may need to manually run secondary installers required by this game. Exit Steam entirely. Browse to your Grand Theft Auto 4 installation folder (Usually `C:\Program Files\Steam\steamapps\common\grand theft auto iv\`)

You will need to run each of the following installers:

```
...\steamapps\common\grand theft auto iv\Installers\DirectX_jun2008\DXSETUP
...\steamapps\common\grand theft auto iv\Installers\DirectX_Mar2009\DXSETUP
...\steamapps\common\grand theft auto iv\Installers\vcredist_x86
```

### Games for Windows Live

Also, install the latest version of the Games For Windows Live software, which can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-US/Live/Pages/livemarketplace.aspx

Restart your computer and test the issue again. If you continue to have difficulty, run this installer:

```
...\steamapps\common\grand theft auto iv\GTAIV\Activation\SteamActivation
```

### References

Taken from [this steam forum post](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showpost.php?p=19715973&postcount=11). In addition, there is another thread of a huge list of GTA IV steam issues which you can find [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=762088).

Answer (score 2):

If your GTA 4 is not running anymore, download and install the [Windows Live Client](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient).

This solved it for me.

Comment: @Oak Pretty much cleaned/censored my post there. Maybe a little too much?

Comment: I understand your frustration - I'd get pretty frustrated if my games stopped running - but rants are not really useful and we generally try to remove them.

Comment: @Oak Ok, thanks for your reply and also understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 9 (beta version) prevented GTA IV from launching for me as well. There were no error dialogs about what happened. Uninstalling the IE9 beta fixed the problem for me.