# GTA 4 Win 8.1 social club does load up but when I click play the loading circle shows up for a second or two but nothing happens

Tags: steam, pc, grand-theft-auto-iv

Yeah thats all that happens.  I bought it on steam digitally.  But theres a ReadMe file in the Gta 4 folder and it has a list of downloads.  Is that what I need or does it not work for windows 8.1? also I have a toshiba not a vista7 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall any existing version of Games for Windows Live via your Computer's Software Panel. Then head over to Microsoft and install this version of it:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5549

(login with Live ID required)

Afterwards, restart your Computer and try again. If it still does not work, set the executable of GTA IV to Compatibility Mode with Vista/7.

In addition, have a look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/gta-iv-will-not-start?rq=1) too.